# How do I check if a user has a certain role in their profile?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Good-day,**

I need some help.  I'm trying to query my MySQL database to see if the currently logged on user to my application has certain rights/role.  If the queried value does exist, then I want to enable a certain menu item.

I checked out most of the similar questions as I was typing my question, but they mostly deal with ASP and JSP so that confuses me even further (as I haven't studied those yet).  I'm still learning VB.Net and MySQL.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here's my code - what am I not doing right?:**

```
Public Sub checkAccessLevel()
    Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection(String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=parts", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password))
    Dim dbQuery As String = "SELECT Level FROM users WHERE username = '" & FormLogin.TextBoxUsername.Text & "'"
    Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(dbQuery, dbConn)
    Dim dbData As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        dbConn.Open()
        dbData = dbAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader
        dbData.Read()
        While dbData.Read
            Select Case UCase(dbData(0).ToString)
                Case Is = "Admin"
                    TSMenuItemOptions.Enabled = True
                Case Is = "Manager"
                    TSMenuItemOptions.Enabled = True
                Case Is = "User"
                    TSMenuItemOptions.Enabled = False
            End Select
        End While
        dbData.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                            vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    Finally
        dbAdapter.Dispose()
        dbConn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my own question as follows;

By modifying the Select Case statement....

**ORIGINAL (Incorrect):**

```
Select Case UCase(dbData(0).ToString)
```

**MODIFIED (Correct):**

```
Select Case dbData(0).ToString
```